# python output formatting to csv

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am trying to create a script which automates the process of running the below tshark command.

```
tshark -T fields -e _ws.col.No -e _ws.col.Time -e _ws.col.Source -e _ws.col.Destination -e _ws.col.Protocol -e _ws.col.Length -e _ws.col.Info -w xxFileNamexx.pcap > xxFileNamexx.csv
```

If I run the above command manually it outputs two files – a .pcap file and a .csv file.  The contents of the .pcap file can be viewd in wireshark, and the .csv file in Excel with the below columns.

**No. Time   Source   Destination   Protocol   Length   Info**

I would like to automate the process of running the tshark command every 5 minutes and output a new .csv file and also a .pcap file, in the same output format as above. The file should be named using the date/time.

So far I have created the script below which successfully runs the tshark command every 5 minutes (for 60sec duration) and outputs a file (using date/time as name), however my formatting must be incorrect as I cannot open it in either wireshark or excel. 
When I try and open the file with wireshark I get any error saying (vwr: Invalid data length 6448693 (runs past the end of the record)) and when I open the file in excel, it appears all data is on a single line, and columns have not been correctly created.

How can the script be amended to output the tshark capture to a .csv file in the same format as when I run the command manually. If possible also to a .pcap file

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
import schedule
import subprocess
import  time

class Sniff:
    def __init__(self, secs):
        self.dir = self.create_dir()
        self.filename =  self.dir +"/" +str(datetime.now())
        print("Capture Traffic")
        self.sniff(secs)

    def sniff(self, sniff_secs):
        command = "tshark -T fields -e _ws.col.No -e _ws.col.Time -e _ws.col.Source -e _ws.col.Destination -e _ws.col.Protocol -e _ws.col.Length -e _ws.col.Info"

        start = datetime.now()

        p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        with open(self.filename,'a+') as f:
             for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ','):
                f.write(str(line))
                if (datetime.now() - start).total_seconds() >= sniff_secs:
                    p.kill()
                    return

        return

    def create_dir(self):
        dirname =str(datetime.now().date())
        try:
            os.mkdir(dirname)
        except FileExistsError:
            pass
        return dirname


if __name__ =='__main__':
    schedule.every(5).minutes.do(Sniff, secs=60 )
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: you shoudl add `-w xxFileNamexx.pcap` into  your `command` Regarding CSV it is output of your command so I can not comment much

Comment: Rehan Azher - if I add the -w xxFileNamexx.pcap to the command it will produce the file once outside of my datestamp folder. I need it to iterate and create the file every 5 minutes thanks

Comment: I think u can specify the full path there. `- w \\Directoyy\\xxFileNamexx.pcap`

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this using the csv module of python to generate a comma separated file.

Initialize the buffer and csv writer:

```
def initialize_data_buffer(): 
      buffer = io.BytesIO()
      filename = [filename]
      wr = csv.writer(buffer, delimiter=',')
      csv_header='column_name_a,column_name_b,column_name_c,......'           
      header = [i.strip() for i in csv_header.split(',')]
      wr.writerow(header)
```

Now you can use writerow method of csv writer to write the data into the buffer using:

```
wr.writerow([List of data to be written])
```

Once you are done write the buffer into the file:

```
data_to_write = buffer.getvalue()
with open(self.filename, "w") as logfile:
    logfile.write(data_to_write)
    logfile.close()
```

Have it:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
import schedule
import subprocess
import  time
import csv
import io
import sys

class Sniff:
    def __init__(self, secs):
        self.dir = self.create_dir()
        self.filename =  self.dir +"/" +str(datetime.now())
        self.buffer = io.StringIO()
        self.wr = csv.writer(self.buffer, delimiter=',')
        csv_header='column_name_a,column_name_b,column_name_c,......'           
        header = [i.strip() for i in csv_header.split(',')]
        self.wr.writerow(header)
        print("Capture Traffic")

        self.sniff(secs)
        self.write_buffer_into_the_file()

    def sniff(self, sniff_secs):
        command = "tshark -T fields -e _ws.col.No -e _ws.col.Time -e _ws.col.Source -e _ws.col.Destination -e _ws.col.Protocol -e _ws.col.Length -e _ws.col.Info"

        start = datetime.now()

        p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        with open(self.filename,'a+') as f:
             for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ','):
                #Make sure that line is a list of data you want to write
                print line
                list_of_data = [line.strip() for line in line.split(',')]

                self.write_in_buffer(list_of_data)
                if (datetime.now() - start).total_seconds() >= sniff_secs:
                    p.kill()
                    return

        return

    def write_in_buffer(self,list_of_data):
        self.wr.writerow(list_of_data)

    def write_buffer_into_the_file(self):
        data_to_write = self.buffer.getvalue()
        with open(self.filename, "w") as logfile:
            logfile.write(data_to_write)


    def create_dir(self):
        dirname =str(datetime.now().date())
        try:
            os.mkdir(dirname)
        except FileExistsError:
            pass
        return dirname


if __name__ =='__main__':
    schedule.every(5).minutes.do(Sniff, secs=60 )
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: thanks @mehul-jain this looks good. To ensure the filename is still created using the dateTime would I replace the sub process in my code with your suggested buffer and csv writer. Sorry I am not coder by trade

Comment: No you should not replace the subprocess command, but make sure that when you read a line from the stdout you are correctly converting it into a list (by spliting over commas or whatever is right). And use the code mentioned above just to write it into a file.

Comment: I have uploaded some amended code, but although the script runs, it now does not write anything to file

Comment: thanks @mehul-jain see comments in your answer for my amendments to code